# python 2.7: why I can't open Tensorboard?

Tags: python-2.7, tensorflow, vagrant, tensorboard

I have installed tensorflow (Tensorflow 1.1.0)with pip on vagrant ubuntu 14.04. And I have a test file which code are as following:

```
import tensorflow as tf

a = tf.add(1, 2,)
b = tf.multiply(a, 3)
c = tf.add(4, 5,)
d = tf.multiply(c, 6,)
e = tf.multiply(4, 5,)
f = tf.div(c, 6,)
g = tf.add(b, d)
h = tf.multiply(g, f)
with tf.Session() as sess:
    writer = tf.summary.FileWriter("test_b/", sess.graph)
    print(sess.run(h))
    writer.close()
```

And I run the

```
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~$ tensorboard --logdir=test_b/
Starting TensorBoard 41 on port 6006
(You can navigate to http://10.0.2.15:6006)
```

But when opened the http://10.0.2.15:6006 in the brower, there is no response and said can't be accessed.

Thanks!

Comment: what happens when you access via `http://localhost:6006` ?

Comment: thanks for comment. Just said that this site can't be accessed, and the site response time is  over time.

Comment: Wait, isn't vagrant a virtualbox system? If so I think you might need to map your ports or something to access the page. I haven't used vagrant so i#m not sure. But that's typically the case with something like docker.

Comment: yes , the vagrant used the virtualbox.

Comment: Ok I think you may have to link your ports then. I think that vagrant is your issue not tensorflow

Comment: thanks for your comments.  Could you tell me how to link my ports in detail. Thanks!

Comment: No. As I said above, I don't have enough knowledge on vagrant to help. I suggest you re-file with a vagrant support group. Perhaps super-user or something. I will add a vagrant tag to this to see if it gets any further support.

Comment: thanks for kind help anyway!